# Derivation of the Dirichlet Kernel in Fourier Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, fourier-series

$$D_N(x)=\sum^{N}_{-N}e^{2\pi inx}=e^{-2\pi iNx}\sum^{2N}_{0}e^{2\pi inx}$$
$$=e^{2\pi iNx}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi i(2N+1)x}-1}{e^{2\pi ix}-1}\right)$$
$$=\frac{e^{2\pi i(N+1/2)}-e^{-2\pi i(N+1/2)x}}{e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi ix}}$$

So I saw this derivation in my textbook. I'm having trouble following the line of reasoning from each line.

From the 1st line to the 2nd line, is $\sum^{2N}_{0}e^{2\pi inx}$ a geometric series?

I am completely lost from the 2nd line to the 3rd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 1st to 2nd you have a geometric sum. From 2nd to 3rd line multiply both numerator and denominator by $e^{-i\pi x}$ and simplify the numerator.

Comment: ah, I see now. Thank you! Regarding the geometric sum. In the book, we are dealing with $1$-periodic functions. Typically on $[0,1]$. Wouldn't $D_N(1)$ be undefined? Or do we just go back and write $D_N(1)=\sum^{N}_{-N}=e^{2\pi in}=\sum^{N}_{-N}(1)=2N$?

Comment: $D_N(1)=2N+1$ and this is also the limiting value of $D_N (x)$ as $x \to 1$.